# How to Display Multiple Labels in One Line with Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a Program that displays text on GUI Screen with Multiple Labels. But all the Labels are showing text in the new line and I want to show text in single line. Code is Below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

win = Tk()
win.title("Label Screen")
win.geometry("800x600+50+50")
win.config(bg='white')

label1=Label(win, text="Label 1", font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), bg='white')
label1.pack(pady=15)

label2=Label(win, text="Label 2", font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), bg='white')
label2.pack(pady=15)

label3=Label(win, text="Label 3", font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), bg='white')
label3.pack(pady=15)

win.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: For this, I think you will have to put your labels in a single label and then pack them. Not super good with Tinker so my knowledge is limited a bit

Comment: Why don't you read about some documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `pack()` method packs to the top, so you'll get a vertical stack of labels by default. You want to pack to the left to easily get all the labels on the same row. To do that, change:

```
labelX.pack(pady=15)
```

to

```
labelX.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=15)
```

Also, it's not ideal to import tkinter twice. Best to import it just once, as

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then make sure to use `tk.` before all the methods, attributes, and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT,pady=15)
label2.pack(side=tk.LEFT,pady=15)
label3.pack(side=tk.LEFT,pady=15)
```

Further read : https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: That's pretty close, but try tk.LEFT instead of tk.Left